# Filtering a list of lists in a smart way

Tags: python

I have a list of lists in the following format

```
a = [[1,...,255],[1,...,255],...,[1,...,255]]
```

i.e. a list of arbitrary length containing lists of integers of fixed length 255.
(The values of the fixed length lists are data from "the real world", and not integers 1 through 255 as in this example.)

Now, I would like to filter out all values in all the inner lists (of length 255), setting them to `0` if their values are above some threshold.

Is there a smart way of doing this without having to write two for loops?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by 'filter out'. Is it not the case that if you find a value in a nested list above a certain value the that sublist is zeroed out ? or is it the sum() of a inner list.

Comment: He wants to set it to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `numpy` to do this very easily:

```
import numpy as np

a = [range(255) for _ in range(10)]
np_a = np.array(a)    
# set all values above 200 to 0
np_a[np_a > 200] = 0
# np_a now contains the data with all values above 200 changed to 0

# if you needed to convert the numpy array back to a python list
a = np_a.tolist()
```

Output to show it working.

```
In [209]: np_a
Out[209]:
array([[  0,   1,   2, ..., 252, 253, 254],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 252, 253, 254],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 252, 253, 254],
       ...,
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 252, 253, 254],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 252, 253, 254],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 252, 253, 254]])

In [210]: np_a[np_a > 252]  = 0

In [211]: np_a
Out[211]:
array([[  0,   1,   2, ..., 252,   0,   0],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 252,   0,   0],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 252,   0,   0],
       ...,
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 252,   0,   0],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 252,   0,   0],
       [  0,   1,   2, ..., 252,   0,   0]])
```

Comment: I just tried that but 'npa' is not defined. I'm interested in seeing results.

Comment: @sotapme -- its a typo, try with `np_a`

Comment: Nice solution. It's how you'd want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

**Variant 1:** Only 1 `for`, for example:

```
dst = []
for s in src:
    dst.append([x if x < 3 else 0 for x in s])
```

**Variant 2:** Without explicit `for`:

```
filter = lambda lst: [x if x < 3 else 0 for x in lst]
dst = [filter(x) for x in src]
```

Comment: how is the list comprehension for a for loop?

Comment: @MattiLyra sorry, not sure to understand your question. Do you mean that list comprehension is implicit kind if "for" cycle?

Comment: Yes, list comprehension are for loops, it's just syntactically nicer. http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: You are right. But what about underlying mechanizm in numpy? Suppose that it is also using cycles. It is just question of "where cycle will be executed". If OP bothering about speed my solution is not optimal and I know it.

Answer (score 0):

```
# arbitarry length list of 255 length lists.    
l = [range(255)]*3 # 3 inner lists (as example)

# get filtered results:
f = [[k if k > 5 else 0 for k in j] for j in l] # filter at value 5 (as example)

# as a function:
def filter(lst, num):
    return [[k if k > num else 0 for k in j] for j in lst]

# as an iter over inner lists.
def filter(lst, num):
    for j in lst:
        yield [k if k > num else 0 for k in j]
```